# CIM in an MVC3 app - how to instantiate ServiceSoap?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, e-commerce, payment-gateway, authorize.net

I'm integrating CIM into an MVC3 app.  I've added a service reference using the development url and coded the following:

```
public long x()
{
    var u = this.User.Identity as IClaimsIdentity;
    var id = u.Claims.First(x => x.ClaimType == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);

    AuthorizeNet.CustomerProfileType cust = new AuthorizeNet.CustomerProfileType();
    cust.merchantCustomerId = id.Value;

    AuthorizeNet.MerchantAuthenticationType merch = new AuthorizeNet.MerchantAuthenticationType();
    merch.name = "8aFRk4663XMd";
    merch.transactionKey = "4MS675e62fQEdUXN";
    AuthorizeNet.ServiceSoap svc = new AuthorizeNet.ServiceSoap();
    AuthorizeNet.CreateCustomerProfileResponseType response = svc.CreateCustomerProfile(
        merch, cust, AuthorizeNet.ValidationModeEnum.none
    );
    return response.customerProfileId;
}
```

but, of course, it doesn't work because one cannot instantiate an interface like that (.ServiceSoap is an interface).  The sample code makes a reference to a .Service - but that doesn't exist AFAICT.

so how is this supposed to work?

TIA - e!

p.s. I did find [an old posting](http://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/Integration-and-Testing/CIM-Integration-as-Service-Reference-to-Class-Library-Project/m-p/16294#M9206) with precisely my problem, but alas, no solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well... at least for now the answer seems to be: don't generate a **Service Reference** but a **Web Reference** (you can do it by clicking on the *Advanced button* of the Service Reference dialogue).

so eeky.